# Decrease the datarate on BLE module for more range

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I'm using a HM-10 BLE module with an Arduino for my project and I really need more range. I have read that on the new Bluetooth 5 spec you can decrease the datarate to get more range, is this possible to do on Bluetooth 4.0 as well?

I really need to get a stable connection about 5-6 meters but it's through concrete and some steel beams. I know this is far from ideal. My connection right now is unstable at +-90 RSSI and I'd only need to get it a little better.

If it's possible to use a Bluetooth 5 module for better range I would consider that as well but it seems that either way I'm still limited to the transmitting power of the iPad which I am going to connect to the HM-10.

> Datasheet for HM-10: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XJQznN6fPFQqAoTVqZh06vhbJ7eF0VFu/view

Comment: Probably not.  If you had the source code for the low level BLE implementation agains the radio (which you do not - it's a binary only library in the TI SDK) you might be able to apply a similar redundant coding scheme, but this would probably not be compatible with what the iPad thinks of as bluetooth 5.  If you want to try this, maybe you should experiment with two iPads or phones or something, but to actually do it you would probably need new embedded hardware.  Don't rule out the possibility that some problem with the way you are *using* BLE in your code is artificially limiting things.

Comment: ie if you only need to move small infrequent amounts of information a *connected* service like BLE serial may not be the best choice.  Something like throwing broadcasts at each others is sporadic and slow but might eventually get the information through, without having state that easily breaks - any state you do need you could work out yourself in a failure-tolerant way.  Though if iOS still has that nasty habit of caching things against MAC address, you'll have to take that into account too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Would a BLEmodule with class 1 be of any use when the iPad has a module with class 2? Or will it still be limited to the limits of class 2?